# how i get img and put it in html by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, attributes

i made a function it takes one parameter should contain a source of img

I tried:

```js
function add(s) {
  let box = document.createElement('div'); // parent
  // img
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = s;

  box.appendChild(img);
  document.body.appendChild(box);
}

add('css\main\imags\laptops.jpg');
```

This is the folder img:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTKIC.png)

Comment: You seem to do it fine, except that you need to escape every backslash in a string literal with another backslash. So `'css\\main\\imags\\laptops.jpg'`. And of course the image needs to exist in the spot you refer to (and the webpage need to have access to it).

Comment: what is the problem? Is the 'img' not working property? And you can just get the html from the debug mode in browser.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer

```js
const imageAdder = (path, selector) => {
  let imageElem = document.createElement("img").src = path;
  let element = document.querySelector(selector);
  element.innerHTML = imageElem
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
imageAdder("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTKIC.png","#element");
});
```

```html
<div id="element">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).